# Определение реального мобильного устройства

Tags: php, javascript, ruby-on-rails, веб-программирование

Все знают, что ботов в сети если не больше, то наравне с реальными пользователями так точно. Задача для web-проекта сугубо для мобильных устройств попытаться минимизировать присутствие ботов.

Проблема использовать `user-agent` в том, что те же инструменты разработчика их успешно имитируют. Есть реализация скрипта, считывающая данные с гироскопа устройства (приведу его ниже), но javascript api не совсем корректно работает в старых версиях Android...

Есть ли еще какие-то варианты определения реальности устройства, кроме приведенного мной? Интересует как клиентская, так и серверная реализации.

```
var gyroPresent = null;
window.addEventListener("devicemotion", function(event) {
  if (event.rotationRate.alpha || event.rotationRate.beta || event.rotationRate.gamma) {
     gyroPresent = true;
  } 
  else {
     gyroPresent = false;
  }
  if (gyroPresent === false) {
     alert('Нет гироскопа');
  }
});
```

Comment: Боту достаточно будет присвоить `gyroPresent = true;` :)

Comment: обычно боты делают предсказуемые запросы. К примеру, человек не может за минуту прокликать 20-30 галочек.

Comment: @Visman, те с которыми сталкивались так не делали. вы явно предусмотрительней их создателей)

Comment: @KoVadim, это давно известный метод, в идеале не ждать пока он прокликает, а сразу его редиректить, к примеру на 404

Comment: @nueq, можно посмотреть в сторону математических вычислений на js. Даете на вход число/а, на выходе должны получить правильный ответ :) https://learn.javascript.ru/number#%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Visman, вы имеете в виду каптчу?

Comment: @nueq, нет, именно вычисления.

Comment: @Visman, можно подробнее?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, читать размеры экрана. У ботов нет экрана)) А вообще 99% ботов не обрабатывают javascript. Так что если js работает, с высокой долей вероятности, можно считать что это не бот.

Comment: Думаю нужно вернуть предыдущую редакцию вопроса. Внимательно редактируйте ваш вопрос, что б не потерять данные.